# What are the possible security settings of an iPhone iOS for the maximum possible security?

Tags: mobile, ios, iphone, data-recovery, cellular

Imagine a nation-state is after you. Is there a list of recommended security settings for the iPhone to give a critical/maximum possible level of local security?

Comment: Not trusting the mobile network would be the first thing. No calls or texts. FaceTime and iMessage *may* be an option depending on how much you trust Apple. Signal/Telegram may be options too.

Comment: Recommended setting: "off". Use a completely different tool to communicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a hardened phone? And you have a state sponsored actor after you? You *should not* be on the internet. Stop using the iPhone, use cheap burners. Because really - there's no way to be sure, not in Apple's ecosystem.

If you choose to disregard the above statement, your best options are to set it up the same way you would to improve your privacy (note the word *improve* instead of *ensure*) -

- Disable script execution
- Don't download any applications
- Don't use any Google or Apple services (@Andre Borie's comment)
- Don't sign in, disable Siri
- Browse only in private mode (heh, placebo)
- Figure out if you can get a version of The Tor Project's browser onto your device
- Wipe it regularly
- Don't add any contacts, not any that can be traced back to you
- Never take photos or screenshots. Of anything.
- Enable the passcode and set it to wipe the device on 10 failed attempts.
- Don't use the fingerprint service.

But really, If you have a government after you, get off the grid.